# How do I delete items from a cursoradapter listview?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I've seen lots of posts regarding this question but none of them guided me through a solution to my problem. I have a listview using a custom cursoradapter which every item has a checkbox in it. This checkbox is not binded to the database, because my intention is to use it for deletion. Once delete button is clicked, all items with checkboxes checked should be deleted from view and database. I implemented the following logic, but turns out the method `<my listview instance>.getCheckedItemPositions()` always returns a `SparseBooleanArray` empty. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I am not sure if this is the best approach anyway, so any other solution or ideas are welcome.

This is my CursorAdapter

```
public class ExpenseCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
private NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
Context context;
private DatabaseHelper db;

public ExpenseCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
}


@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    // when the view will be created for first time,
    // we need to tell the adapters, how each item will look
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expense_single_row_item, parent, false); 

    return retView;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    // here we are setting our data
    // that means, take the data from the cursor and put it in views

    TextView textViewParticipantId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_expense_participant);
    textViewParticipantId.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));

    TextView textViewExpenseDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_expense_description);
    textViewExpenseDescription.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("description")));

    TextView textViewExpenseAmount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_expense_amount);
    textViewExpenseAmount.setText(formatter.format(Double.valueOf(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("amount")))));



}

}
```

This is my item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:stretchColumns="1,2,3" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="10" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb_expense_row"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:button="@drawable/selector_check"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:padding="2dip" 
        android:weightSum="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_expense_participant"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:weightSum="3" 
        android:gravity="left"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_expense_description"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:weightSum="3" 
        android:gravity="left"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_expense_amount"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:gravity="left" />
</TableRow>
```

And this is the activity with the logic I am using on delete button --removeExpense():

```
private static final String TAG = ExpenseActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private ListView listView;
private ExpenseCursorAdapter customAdapter;
private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
private long eventId;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_expense);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    eventId = getIntent().getLongExtra("tag_event_id", -1);

    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);


    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.expense_list_data);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d(TAG, "clicked on item: " + position+" - ID: "+id);
        }
    });



    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            customAdapter = new ExpenseCursorAdapter(ExpenseActivity.this, databaseHelper.getAllExpensesByEventCursor(eventId));
            listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

        }
    });

    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
 }
 ...
 private void removeExpenses() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Remove Expense button clicked on");

    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    SparseBooleanArray checkedItemPositions  = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();

    int itemCount = listView.getCount();        

    for (int i = itemCount - 1; i >=0; i--) {
        if (checkedItemPositions.valueAt(i)) {

            //db.deleteExpense(listView.getItemIdAtPosition(checkedItemPositions.keyAt(i)));
            db.deleteExpense(listView.getItemIdAtPosition(i));

        }

        customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    checkedItemPositions.clear();

    listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

    listView.clearChoices();

    if (db != null){
        db.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: If you were able to solve your problem, then please post the solution as the answer so that others will get benefited from it.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not solve the problem. I had to put this on hold since then.